# Azure Frontdoor Dynamic Block not working in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-front-door

Im having some issues with coding a dynamic block for frontdoor in Terraform. I have found a good working example of one here: https://github.com/spy86/terraform-azure-front-door/blob/main/front_door.tf

Yet my frontdoor setup is not as complex as this persons and I do not need everything he has done on his.

What I am trying to achieve is to put two backend_pools on my front door to enable multiple regions. The only way to do this is to bring in dynamic blocks. Yet when I do this I am getting an error: `│ Error: Unsupported attribute │ │   on frontdoor.tf line 96, in resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "jctestingfrontdoor": │   96:         for_each = var.backend_pool_settings.value.backend[*] │     ├──────────────── │     │ var.backend_pool_settings is a list of object, known only after apply │ │ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?`

Here is my Frontdoor code:

Main.tf

```html
resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "jctestingfrontdoor" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault,
  ]
  name                = "testingfrontdoor"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Terraform.name
  routing_rule {
    name               = "projroutingrule"
    accepted_protocols = ["Http", "Https"]
    patterns_to_match  = ["/*"]
    frontend_endpoints = ["projfrontendendpoint", "${local.frontendendpoint2}"]
    forwarding_configuration {
      forwarding_protocol = "MatchRequest"
      backend_pool_name   = "projbackendpool"
    }
  }

  backend_pool_load_balancing {
    name                        = "projloadbalancesettings"
    sample_size                 = 255
    successful_samples_required = 1
  }

  backend_pool_health_probe {
    name                = "projhealthprobesettings"
    path                = "/health/probe"
    protocol            = "Https"
    interval_in_seconds = 240
  }

  dynamic "backend_pool" {
    for_each = var.backend_pool_settings[*]
    content {
      name                = var.backend_pool_settings.name
      load_balancing_name = var.backend_pool_settings.load_balancing_name
      health_probe_name   = var.backend_pool_settings.health_probe_name

      dynamic "backend" {
        for_each = var.backend_pool_settings.backend
        content {
          address     = var.backend_pool_settings.address
          host_header = var.backend_pool_settings.host_header
          http_port   = var.backend_pool_settings.http_port
          https_port  = var.backend_pool_settings.https_port
          priority    = var.backend_pool_settings.priority
          weight      = var.backend_pool_settings.weight
          enabled     = var.backend_pool_settings.enabled
        }
      }
    }
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = "projfrontendendpoint"
    host_name = format("testingfrontdoor.azurefd.net")
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = local.frontendendpoint2
    host_name = format("portal-staging.terraform.example")
  }

}




resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "portal_staging_https_config" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_frontdoor.jctestingfrontdoor
  ]
  frontend_endpoint_id              = "${azurerm_frontdoor.jctestingfrontdoor.id}/frontendEndpoints/${local.frontendendpoint2}"
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = true

  custom_https_configuration {
    certificate_source                      = "AzureKeyVault"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name = "imported-cert"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id    = azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault.id
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```html
variable "backend_pool_settings" {
  description = "backend pool stettings for frontdoor"
  type = object({
    name = string
    backend = list(object({
      address     = string
      host_header = string
      http_port   = number
      https_port  = number
      weight      = number
      priority    = number
      enabled     = bool
    }))
    load_balancing_name = string
    health_probe_name   = string
  })
}
```

locals.tf

```html
locals {
  frontendendpoint2 = "projfrondoordnsname"
  backendpool1      = "uksouth"
  backendpool2      = "westeurope"
}
```

inputvariables.tfvars

```html
backend_pool_settings = (
{
  name = "uksouth"
  backend = {
    address     = "portal-staging-testing1.terraform.example"
    host_header = "portal-staging-testing1.terraform.example"
    http_port   = 80
    https_port  = 443
    priority    = 1
    weight      = 50
    enabled     = true
  }
  load_balancing_name = "projloadbalancesettings"
  health_probe_name   = "projloadbalancesettings"
  },
  {
  name = "westeurope"
  backend = {
    address     = "portal-staging-testing2.terraform.example"
    host_header = "portal-staging-testing2.terraform.example"
    http_port   = 80
    https_port  = 443
    priority    = 1
    weight      = 50
    enabled     = true
  }
  load_balancing_name = "projloadbalancesettings"
  health_probe_name   = "projloadbalancesettings"
})
```

I have coded the variables as object lists but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do and I'm not sure if I should be splitting the backend_pool as two dynamic blocks like in the example.

UPDATE:

After working through my code I have simplified it a bit more,

```html
    resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "jctestingfrontdoor" {
      depends_on = [
        azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault,
      ]
      name                = "testingfrontdoor"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Terraform.name
      routing_rule {
        name               = "projroutingrule"
        accepted_protocols = ["Http", "Https"]
        patterns_to_match  = ["/*"]
        frontend_endpoints = ["projfrontendendpoint", "${local.frontendendpoint2}"]
        forwarding_configuration {
          forwarding_protocol = "MatchRequest"
          backend_pool_name   = "projbackendpool"
        }
      }

      backend_pool_load_balancing {
        name                        = "projloadbalancesettings"
        sample_size                 = 255
        successful_samples_required = 1
      }

      backend_pool_health_probe {
        name                = "projhealthprobesettings"
        path                = "/health/probe"
        protocol            = "Https"
        interval_in_seconds = 240
      }

      backend_pool {
     name        = "projbackendpool"
     dynamic "backend" {
        for_each = var.backend_pool_settings.value.backend[*]
        content {
          address     = backend.address
          host_header = backend.host_header
          http_port   = backend.http_port
          https_port  = backend.https_port
          priority    = backend.priority
          weight      = backend.weight
          enabled     = backend.enabled
        }
      }
      load_balancing_name = "projloadbalancesettings"
      health_probe_name   = "projhealthprobesettings"
    }

      frontend_endpoint {
        name      = "projfrontendendpoint"
        host_name = format("testingfrontdoor.azurefd.net")
      }

      frontend_endpoint {
        name      = local.frontendendpoint2
        host_name = format("portal-staging.terraform.example")
      }

    }
```

Now the error im getting is: `│ Error: Unsupported attribute │ │   on frontdoor.tf line 96, in resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "jctestingfrontdoor": │   96:         for_each = var.backend_pool_settings.value.backend[*] │     ├──────────────── │     │ var.backend_pool_settings is a list of object, known only after apply │ │ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?`

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this by playing about with the map variable. Basically, front door does not require the object of the backend to be specified as it already knows its building a backend. Also I played around with a few bits of other code and got this working see my code for example:

```html
mainj.tf

resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "jctestingfrontdoor" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault,
  ]
  name                = "testingfrontdoor"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.terraform.name
  routing_rule {
    name               = "projroutingrule"
    accepted_protocols = ["Http", "Https"]
    patterns_to_match  = ["/*"]
    frontend_endpoints = ["projfrontendendpoint", "${local.frontendendpoint2}"]
    forwarding_configuration {
      forwarding_protocol = "MatchRequest"
      backend_pool_name   = "projbackendpool"
    }
  }

  backend_pool_load_balancing {
    name                        = "projloadbalancesettings"
    sample_size                 = 255
    successful_samples_required = 1
  }

  backend_pool_health_probe {
    name                = "projhealthprobesettings"
    path                = "/health/probe"
    protocol            = "Https"
    interval_in_seconds = 240
  }

  backend_pool {
     name        = "projbackendpool"
     dynamic "backend" {
        for_each = var.backend_pool_settings
        content {
          address     = backend.value.address
          host_header = backend.value.host_header
          http_port   = backend.value.http_port
          https_port  = backend.value.https_port
          priority    = backend.value.priority
          weight      = backend.value.weight
          enabled     = backend.value.enabled
        }
      }
      load_balancing_name = "projloadbalancesettings"
      health_probe_name   = "projhealthprobesettings"
    }
  
  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = "projfrontendendpoint"
    host_name = format("testingfrontdoor.azurefd.net")
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = local.frontendendpoint2
    host_name = format("portal-staging.terraform.example")
  }

}

resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "portal_staging_https_config" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_frontdoor.jctestingfrontdoor
  ]
  frontend_endpoint_id              = "${azurerm_frontdoor.jctestingfrontdoor.id}/frontendEndpoints/${local.frontendendpoint2}"
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = true

  custom_https_configuration {
    certificate_source                      = "AzureKeyVault"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name = "imported-cert"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id    = azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault.id
  }
}

variables.tf

variable "backend_pool_settings" {
  description = "backend pool stettings for frontdoor"
  type = map(object({
      address     = string
      host_header = string
      http_port   = number
      https_port  = number
      weight      = number
      priority    = number
      enabled     = bool
  }))
}

inputvariables.tfvars

backend_pool_settings = {
  backendone = {
    address     = "portal-staging-testing1.terraform.example"
    host_header = "portal-staging-testing1.terraform.example"
    http_port   = 80
    https_port  = 443
    priority    = 1
    weight      = 50
    enabled     = true
  },

  backendtwo = {
    address     = "portal-staging-testing2.terraform.example"
    host_header = "portal-staging-testing2.terraform.example"
    http_port   = 80
    https_port  = 443
    priority    = 1
    weight      = 50
    enabled     = true
  }
}
```

This post also helped me to figure out messing about with map objects with Terraform: https://serverfault.com/questions/1063395/terraform-values-from-tfvars-are-not-loading-when-using-multi-level-maps